# Procedural Texture transparency

Tags: texturing, transparency, procedural

I'm very nooby in Blender :) I'd like to create some texture like on this tutorial below, but I'd like that the fill of stones (blue colors) became transparent. I'd like to see only the shape between the stones. How can I do that?

[Procedural Texture for Stylized Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1Ud25ycHvk)

Thank you

Comment: you may have to be more specific to get a good answer.  If you can, provide a mock-up of what you want, even a crude drawing on top of the image would help

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a mask of some sort (*ie* greyscale data in the form of an image texture or procedural texture), here a Voronoi texture, you can pipe it into a *Mix Shader* node and plug a *Transparent BSDF* into one of its inputs.